# Search for patterns

Tags: regex

I have a database that contains verbs and information about these verbs. The information is in parentheses and always follows the verb. Example:

tántyjë' ë chòn (5.53.3.1) bántyjë' ë chòn (5.53.3 1) nngwántyjë' é chòn (5.5.53.3.1) kwántyjë' ë chòn (5.53.3.1)

I am looking for an expression that isolates each verb followed by its information in brackets.
Example : **tántyjë' ë chòn (5.53.3.1)**
This is 1 pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following regex:

```
(?<verb>[^(]+) (?<info>\([^\)]+\)) ?
```

Explanation:

- `(?<verb>[^(]+)`: Group containing the verb

  - `[^(]+`: combination of characters other than open parenthesis
- : a space
- `(?<info>\([^\)]+\))`: Group containing the information

  - `\(`: open parenthesis
  - `[^\)]+`: combination of characters other than closed parenthesis
  - `\)`: closed parenthesis
- `?`: optional ending space

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kJQJWi/1).